# C++ Builder File Version not correct

Tags: preprocessor, c++builder, compiler-directives, c++builder-xe7, fileversioninfo

I have set the file version in Project->Options->Version Info (yes the "Include version information" is ticked).

I have for example  FileVersion: 0.95.1.73 set in all release configurations.
But when I rebuild, the File version is always set to 0.7.8.28

It doesn't matter what I set the FileVersion to, I always get 0.7.8.28.
The Copyright text is also from a very old version.

I tried to clean delete all files obj, res, tds etc in the Win32/Release folder of the project. But same result every time.

The project file (XML) do have the new FileVersion of 0.95.1.73.
This problem only happen on Release config, Debug config is working fine.

Any clue of where to look? Any compiler/preprocessor directives that can override this?

Comment: You may enjoy installting [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) which provides a replacement for the Version Info setting. It has a bit of a quirky UI but it makes the correct settings.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no compiler/precompiler directive to override this.  You have a conflicting version resource defined somewhere.  If it is not in the `.cproj` file (which can have multiple build configurations defined, each with their own version info), then there has to be an offending `.rc`/`.res` file somewhere on your project's search path that is being linked into the final executable.  Version info does not come from anywhere else, it is either defined in the project itself, or it is linked from a resource script/file.